# Beamer Customization

Tags: beamer, titles, presentations, logos

I am a LaTeX sympathizer, however, I'm just new at this.

I even did a model, attached.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % codificacao de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % codificacao de fontes
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}          % idioma
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}        % tema
\usecolortheme{whale}               % cores
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % fonte modo matematico

    \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
    \begin{textblock*}{100mm}(\textwidth,-0.9cm)
      \hspace{-1cm}  \includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{suse}
    \end{textblock*}}

\title[\sc{Texto no rodap\'e}]{Modelo do Beamer - Digite o titulo}
\author[digite seu Nome]{digite seu Nome}
\institute{nome do instituto} % opcional
\date{\today}
```

The result was that:

[image]

but, I would like a line below the slide title, resulting in:

[image]

And I would like the logo before the title!

[image]

**So can I count on you to help me out?**

I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout can be achieved with a redefined frametitle template:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % codificacao de caracteres
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % codificacao de fontes
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}          % idioma
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}        % tema
\usecolortheme{whale}               % cores
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} % fonte modo matematico
\usepackage{textpos}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{frametitle}{}{\nointerlineskip}%
  \@tempdima=\textwidth%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@leftmargin%
  \advance\@tempdima by\beamer@rightmargin%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{frametitle}
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
    \vbox{}\vskip-1ex%
    \raisebox{-1ex}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}{.88\paperwidth}
    \if@tempswa\else\csname beamer@fteleft\endcsname\fi%
    \strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
    {%
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
      {\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\strut\par}%
      \fi
    }%
      \end{minipage}
    \vskip-1ex%
    \if@tempswa\else\vskip-.3cm\fi% set inside beamercolorbox... evil here...
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vskip-2.4ex%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1.5pt,left,wd=\the\@tempdima]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}    
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=blue}

\title[\sc{Texto no rodap\'e}]{Modelo do Beamer - Digite o titulo}
\author[digite seu Nome]{digite seu Nome}
\institute{nome do instituto} % opcional
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]